# 2d bilinear interpolation in R

Tags: r, interpolation

I have some multidimensional data structures that I need to do some interpolation on. I'm really finding it difficult to get an example of how to do this in R!

As an example if I have the array, `old`:

```
old <- array(runif(10*12), dim=c(12,10))

str(old)
num [1:12, 1:10] 0.763 0.429 0.792 0.923 0.476 ...
```

what I would like to do is make the array `new`:

```
new <- interp2d(old, newx=6, newy=5)
```

i.e. I want to change the dimensions of the array so that new is a 6*5 array of the `old` data -- in this example it would be important to preserve the totals in the `old` grid. The line above is an example of what I would like to do, I don't know how to and was hoping someone would??! Thanks!

Comment: A `??interpolate` shows (for me) `stats::approx` (in base R), `spatstat::interp.im` and `fBasics::linearInterp` and `e1071::interpolate`. Perhaps one of these could work? (I'd be interested in a base-R solution not needing extra packages, but `stats::approx` looks a little unwieldy in that it returns a list).

Comment: This is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171904/r-apply-fun-to-kxk-subsections-of-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a start, but not I'm sure it does what you want (preserve totals).  In fact, I'm not sure I see how you can exactly preserve the totals when you're coarsening in this way ... unless you'd rather "bin" than "interpolate"?

```
library(sos)
findFn("{bilinear interpolation}")

set.seed(101)
old <- array(runif(10*12), dim=c(12,10))

library(fields)

interp2d <- function(old, newx, newy) {
  interp.surface.grid(list(x=seq(nrow(old)),y=seq(ncol(old)),z=old),
                      list(x=seq(1,nrow(old),length=newx),
                           y=seq(1,ncol(old),length=newy)))$z
}

newmat <- interp2d(old, newx=6, newy=5)
```

Comment: Thanks Ben! This seems to do what I need. Its a shame it requires something other than the base package (i.e. fields) but it works so I'm happy!